# Positive semidefinitness

Tags: linear-algebra

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
7 & 8 \\
21 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Why is the construction $P = A A^\top$ guaranteed to produce a positive semidefinite matrix?  For which $x$ would $x^\top P x=0$?

Let $Y_{3 \times 1}$ be a $3 \times 1$ matrix and $Y=\begin{pmatrix}y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y_3\end{pmatrix}$ and consider $Y^\top P Y$.

Then,
\begin{align}
Y^\top P Y &= Y^\top A A^\top Y \\
& = \left(A^\top Y\right)^\top \left(A^\top Y\right) \\
& =U^\top U, \qquad U=A^\top Y \\
& =u_{11}^2+u_{21}^2, \qquad U=\begin{pmatrix}
u_{11} \\
u_{21}
\end{pmatrix} \\
& \geqslant 0.
\end{align}

How do I continue?

Comment: You're done! Note that you show that the product is $0$ iff $U = 0$ so if $A^TY= 0$  i.e. if you're in the kernel of $A^T$

Comment: Thanks, how do I find x? @OsamaGhani

Comment: Not sure I'm following. You've shown that $P = AA^T$ is positive semidefinite i.e. $x^TPx \geq 0$ with $x^TPx = 0$ iff $A^Tx = 0$. Solutions to that are given by any methods you've learned in linear algebra

Comment: Note that $A^tx=0$ is a homogeneous system of two equations in three unknowns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symmetry: the resulting matrix $P$ is a symmetric since $(AA^T)^T = AA^T$.

Positive Semidefiniteness: For any vector $x$, the quadratic form $x^TPx$ evaluates to a non-negative value.
\begin{align} x^T Px &= x^T(AA^T)x \\ &= (A^T x)^T(A^T x) \\ &= \|A^Tx\|^2 \\ &\geq 0. \end{align}
The expression $\|A^Tx\|^2 $ is the squared Euclidean norm of the vector $A^Tx$, which is always non-negative. This shows that the matrix $P$ is positive semidefinite.

For the second part, we can see that $x^TPx =0$ if and only if $A^Tx=0$.

Comment: Nice answer. In addition, $P$ is positive definite if $A$ has full row rank.